# Notation for "set of functions that satisfy all Dirichlet boundary conditions"

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In learning to derive weak forms in the context of finite element methods, I am working through "Finite Element Methods: A Practical Guide" (Whiteley 2017), and the following demand on the properties of test functions $v$ is imposed,

[image]

but **how could this be written with strictly mathematical notation?** For completeness, note that $H_E^1(a,b) \subset H^1$ where $H^1$ is the Sobolev space of order 1.

(Edited based on comment) I believe it could be partially written as follows:

$$
H_E^1(a, b) = \{v \in H^1(a, b)\ |\ v : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ v\ \text{satisfies all Dirichlet boundary conditions} \}
$$

or more generally for a domain $\Omega$ of dimension $d$,

$$
H_E^1(\Omega) = \{v \in H^1(\Omega)\ |\ v : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ v\  \text{satisfies all Dirichlet boundary conditions} \}
$$

Comment: My greatest objection would be that $v(x)$ is a function value and not a function.

Comment: @gerw The book I am following also states "substitute suitable test functions $\phi(x, y) \in S_0^h(\Omega)$", based on what you say about $v(x)$ being a function value, shouldn't the correct notation in the book then be something like $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ |\ \phi \in S_0^h(\Omega)$? My maths background is admittedly not very strong, so I apologize if my proposition looks like nonsense.

Comment: Your function $\phi$ should be defined on $\Omega$, i.e., $\phi \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$. Similarly, for $v$ in the definitions of your sobolev spaces. I would just write $H^1_E(\Omega) = \{ v \in H^1(\Omega) \mid v \text{ satisfies the Dirichlet BCs}\}$, since the mapping properties of $v$ are already "encoded" in $v \in H^1(\Omega)$.